# How to use Apollo's multiple useQuery() hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I need to use 2 queries in my file and I am writing them like so:

```
const {loading, data } = useQuery(getCharactersQuery);
const {loading, data} = useQuery(getSingleCharacterQuery);
```

The problem is, they both have the same "loading" and "data" variables and I don't see anywhere in the docs how can we have different ones. How can I differentiate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **Object destructuring** of JS [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You can choose not to use it here to give different variable names.

```
const resCharacters = useQuery(getCharactersQuery);
const resSingleCharacter = useQuery(getSingleCharacterQuery);

if (resCharacters.loading || resSingleCharacter.loading) return 'Loading...';
...
```

---

- Ref: Apollo document of [useQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query)

Answer (score 3):

This way, by giving them an alias.

```
const {loading, data } = useQuery(getCharactersQuery);
const {loading: singleCharacterLoading, data: singleCharacterData} = useQuery(getSingleCharacterQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const GET_DATA = gql`
  query {
    characters {
      phone
      rating
      ratingType
      review
      city
      id
    }
    singleCharacter {
      title
      text
    }
  }
`;

const {loading, data } = useQuery(GET_DATA);

console.log(data) //{characters: [...], singleCharacter: [...]}
```

Comment: The author specifically asked how to solve this when they need to use more than one query. Also, please explain your code / the idea behind it and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Obviously, the request goes to one database, so we can combine several requests into one.